# Google Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API - What is the row unique key?

Tags: google-analytics-api

We save data of each day and aggregate it locally by given period dates.

I build a complex key by the path items in `mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath` :

```
type OR type_campaignId OR type_(campaignName) X each channel
```

example:

path of 1:

```
id = "direct" 
id = "referral"
id = "paid_search_13021478763"
```

path of 2:

```
id = "referral_direct"
id = "organic_search_paid_search_11278552753"
```

and so on...

Is it good enough ? Is there a better way to set the unique key for each row?